# can we read android machine id?

Tags: java, android, flash, flash-builder

I am trying to create native extension for flash using java and flash builder. I need unique id to determine the device. I can retrieve android id and device id but it seems not reliable. So I was thinking reading machine id. Is it possible ? Or is there any unique id that I can use ?

Comment: Knowing essentially nothing about Flash -- It might help to know what you intend to accomplish by using this "machine id" you refer to.

Comment: by machine id I mean something like machine serial number or anything that is unique which can identify the device.

Comment: Aside from the Android id and the device id, I don't think there is any other, more reliable previously generated id to use.

Comment: what does build.serial return ? Is it reliable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get IMEI number, its unique. Here is the code.

```
String identifier = null;
 TelephonyManager tm =   (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 if (tm != null)
  identifier = tm.getDeviceId();
 if (identifier == null || identifier .length() == 0)
  identifier = Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

OR

You can use MAC address.

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
String mMacAddress = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

But this is also not reliable. If the device does not have wifi then MAC address returns null.

You will get more information regarding unique id from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/How-to-retrieve-the-Device-Unique-ID-from-android-device)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i already mentioned I can retrieve device id and android id and it doesn't seems reliable.